# How do I convert this particular excel calculation to sql calculation in aws redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data in table where the columns are date,customer,category, quantity1,quantity2,quantity3, now I need to calculate the new calculated quantity using quantity columns.This how it done in excel. Could anyone help me write redshift sql query for the above.

[image]

Comment: Use the `lag` function to get the prior record. That's the hard part. Do you know how to achieve `IF` and adding up columns? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html

Comment: How can I lag over the column that is being created by the same query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  First you need to identify the groups.  These seem based on `quantity3` not being `null`.  You can use a cumulative `count()` for that purpose.

Next, you can use window functions for the final calculation.  That looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (max(quantity3) over (partition by customer, grp) +
        coalesce(sum(quantity1 + quantity2) over
                     (partition by customer, grp
                      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                     ), 0
                )
       ) as calculation
from (select t.*,
             count(quantity3) over (partition by customer order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: please help me understand how this query could reference the calculation of the same column it created by itself

Comment: @GuravaRaju . . . It isn't.  It is doing the cumulative sum calculation that you are doing in Excel.